Why does R-Pi Pico not read pin status when running from battery
Simple code: read the status (high or low) of a pin. The pin is either left unconnected, or connected to a ground pin on the Pico. It works when the Pico is powered from USB from a Windows PC, but not when powered by a 5v power block into the Pico micro-usb connector, then the pin is never seen "low"
Tried on several pins of the Pico, all the same.
Using Micropython v 20240602-v1.23.0
My code: Copied to Pico as main.py:
from machine import Pin
import uos
import sys 
import utime

# assign Pico pins NB pin numbers are GPIO numbers
En = Pin(3, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)

LED = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)          # internal LED

#MAIN
if En.value() == 0:
    LED.value(1)
    sys.exit()

if En.value() == 1:
    i = 0
    while i < 50:
        utime.sleep(0.1)
        LED.toggle()
        i += 1

LED.value(0)
sys.exit()


I'm using Thonny to develop the script...

Why do you think this is a software problem? You're trying to read an unconnected pin. An unconnected pin may show any value, depending on the environment. You're changing the power supply which might have unexpected consequences.

The pin is not unconnected, it is pulled up to 3.3v. And the power supply is certainly having unexpected consequences!

I’m going to guess that when the board is connected to your PC you run the code from Thonny with the board already powered up, whereas with the power block you are plugging the board into the power block and observing the LED.
I’d start by seeing if this is related to the board’s behaviour on powering up. I’d see what happens if you add utime.sleep(1) after the imports, or put a loop around the #main code.
Once the board is stable, the PULL_UP should mean the pin isn’t floating.

Thanks for rapid responses, improved code below, now working:
from machine import Pin
import uos
import sys 
import utime
utime.sleep(1)              # suggestion from SO
# assign Pico pins NB pin numbers are GPIO numbers
En = Pin(3, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
LED = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)      # internal LED
#MAIN                       revised after initial SO comments
while True:
    if En.value() == 0:     # pin low
        tick = 0.05
    elif En.value() == 1:   # pin high
        tick = 0.5    
    else:
        tick = 5            # should never happen
    LED.toggle()
    utime.sleep(tick)

